# Get accurate date and time from the server ( Prevent local time )

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime

I've been trying to get time from the server using different methods like **Date.Now()** and **Carbon::now()** but the problem with this approach is the visitor is easily able to change his/her computer time and the return response from the server will change according to the visitor time on the computer.

---

Here's what i am actually trying to do

I have 6 different questions in the database that i would like to show on different days.

For example: On 20 November, 2019 i would like to show the Question #1 and on 24 November, 2019 i would like to show the Question #2

The problem here is, If the visitor changes his date to 24 November, He will be able to see the question in advance whereas i only want them to know this question on the date i specified in the system.

This is how i am sending a response back to my AJAX call.

```
public function getSer(Request $request)
{
    $now = new DateTime('now',new DateTimezone('America/New_York'));
    return response()->json($now);
}
```

The returned time is based on the local client time and not the server.

I've also tried the following:

```
$question = Questions::where('question_start', '<=', Carbon::now('America/New_York'))->where('question_end', '>=', Carbon::now('America/New_York'))->first();
        dd($question);
```

But the results are changing as i change date on my operating system

Comment: What is your use case? You should trust the user's date and time, but prevent people from doing things on the server by implementing a date/time check. So if they request a resource that isn't available until a specific time, then your server would return a 401 unauthorized and then a 200 when the date/time has been met. The UI would prevent showing the option for this resource based on the device's time. If their time is out of sync, oh well. Most stuff these days don't work if the device time is wrong anyways.

Comment: Datetimes you create on the server with for example PHP are independent of client computers. I am sure you forgot some details in your question.

Comment: Question updated, Please check and sorry for any confusions.

Comment: Still not clear. `Date.Now()` looks like JS, so that would mean that you use the client date/time. In a PHP (on the server) you will get the server time.

Comment: I have tried Carbon::now() and date function on the server side as well and returned the response using an Ajax call but it still changes according to the client date/time

Comment: @NMindz  Is the question selected by Javascript?  If so, that's where your problem is, not the date manipulation.  Perform the question-selection logic server-side (PHP)

Comment: Please show the code actually being used.  Without that, this is quite unclear and we're all just guessing.

Comment: With the client passing their time and timezone, you could make a threshold of like +- 5 minutes and check if the time they passed matches your server side UTC (taking into account timezone offset). That way you could detect them changing the time (although not the timezone).

Comment: I have updated the question, I hope it's a bit more clear now

Comment: Is your PHP/webserver running locally on your computer or on a remote server?

Comment: My bad, I am testing it on local server, I will quickly do the changes online and test again. Sorry for all the hassle.

Comment: @PatrickQ it worked now, Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple:

> Perform the date/time check on the server and render the question

Something like this:

```php
<?php
$question_one_start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s','2019-11-20 00:00:00',new DateTimezone('America/New_York'));
$question_one_end = clone $question_one_start;
$question_one_end->modify('+1 day');
$now = new DateTime('now',new DateTimezone('America/New_York'));
if($now >= $question_one_start && $now < $question_one_end){
    echo "Question output here.";
}
else if( ... ) {
    ....
}
```

With this you don't need to perform any kind of date/time check on the client.

Comment: I have updated the question, I hope it's a bit more clear now

Comment: I was testing on a local environment and getting wrong results, Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Date/time presentation is a client/UI issue. The client should take the time that the server returned (whether it is in UTC or not), and convert it to the client's local time zone.

EDIT due to updated question: I still don't see the issue. The server is responsible for fetching questions up to (I assume) the current date. It doesn't matter what the client's date/time is. The server will still only fetch and return questions for the current date. If the client changes their date to the year 2100, that doesn't impact the query that the server is doing.

Perhaps the problem is that you are letting the client specify the date/time query range, instead of the server?

Comment: I don't really want to convert the time to localtime, I just want to display the time of the server in whatever time zone is set.

Comment: That sounds like a contradiction, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Question updated, Please check and sorry for any confusions.